# How to remove a column from a data file in C

Tags: c, file, format, dataset

I am trying to remove a column from a data set. My file looks as below. How can I accomplish this?

Input-

```
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6
```

Output-

```
2,3
3,4
4,5
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? (That's not a data set, BTW; it's a CSV (Comma Separated Value) text file.)

Comment: Check out [libcsv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no quick way of doing that - you will end up "tokenizing" each line of the file, and then writing only the parts that you want.

If you know that each row contains a fixed number of integers (say, 4, as in your example), and you need to "cut out" several columns from it (say, columns 2 and 3), do this in a loop:

```
int a,b;
fscanf(inFile, "%*d,%d,%d,%*s", &a, &b);
fprintf(outFile, "%d,%d\n", a, b);
```

Of course you need to open the files before you start looping, close after you finish it, and test for the end of the input file in your loop condition.